# Read subfolder files by giving inner subfolder files priority?

Tags: c#, linq, file, asp.net-core, recursion

I have a code which reads file from all the subfolders (folder1, folder2, ...) by giving priority to `dev` folders file for each subfolder as shown below:

```
Products
├── folder1
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files1.json
│   ├── files1.json
│   ├── files2.json
│   ├── files3.txt
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files1.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files1.json
├── folder2
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── files5.json
│   ├── files4.json
│   ├── files5.json
│   ├── files6.txt
│   ├── prod
│   │   └── files5.json
│   └── stage
│       └── files5.json
└── folder3
    ├── files10.json
    ├── files7.json
    ├── files8.json
    └── files9.txt
```

Below is the code I have which does the job but I was thinking can we do the same below logic using `linq` in much simpler way if there is any? Meaning give priority to `dev` folders first in each sub-folder and then read all files from sub-folder level.

```
private IList<string> ReadFiles(string path)
{
    var allFiles = new List<string>();
    var subFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).ToList();
    var fileType = new List<string>() { "*.json", "*.txt" };
    for (int i = 0; i < fileType.Count; i++)
    {
        foreach (var sub in subFolders)
        {
            var jsonFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sub, fileType[i], SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
            var subSubFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(sub).Where(x => x.Contains("dev")).ToList();
            if (subSubFolders.Count > 0)
            {
                var subDev = jsonFiles.Where(x => x.Contains("dev")).ToList();
                jsonFiles.RemoveAll(x => x.Contains("dev"));
                foreach (var item in jsonFiles)
                {
                    var dd = subDev.Where(x => System.IO.File.ReadLines(x).SequenceEqual(System.IO.File.ReadLines(item))).FirstOrDefault();
                    allFiles.Add(dd == null ? item : dd);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in jsonFiles)
                {
                    allFiles.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return allFiles;
}
```

Comment: You can enumerate all `*.json` and `*.txt` files in all subfolders, then check the full path, whether it contains `dev` subfolder or not. Or group by file name (if it's unique for entire `Products` folder)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Can you provide an example on how this will work? I am just confuse on how to check the full path and do all this efficiently. File name is not unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to list all the json/txt files within a folder hierarchy, and process those in a folder named `dev` first:

```
var sc = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase; //because it makes things less wordy later

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //all files in all folders

var interestingFiles = files.Where(f => ".json .txt".Contains(Path.GetExtension(f), sc)); //only json/txt files

var devFilesFirst = interestingFiles.OrderByDescending(f => Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(f)).Equals("dev", sc)); //dev files first. bool sorts false(0) then true(1) so we orderby desc

foreach(var file in devFilesFirst )
  ...
```

Your code runs the directory search once per filter extension, which is a bit inefficient and it's also a bit odd that you enumerate the directories of the starting path, then enumerate the files in all those returned directories; you could just enumerate the starting path, no?

So in this code above we enumerate all files in all directories, and reject those which aren't json or txt, then we order by whether it's a file in the `dev` named folder or not. This uses GetDirectoryName followed by GetFileName to pull just the dir name. You could also use `Path.GetDirectoryName(f).EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "dev", sc)` but it's a bit verbose IMHO

---

Re the "don't process stage/file1.json if we already processed dev/file1.json":

We track dev files we already saw:

```
var alreadySeen = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var f in devFilesFirst){
  var fnameLower = Path.GetFileName(f).ToLower();

  if(alreadySeen.Contains(fnameLower))
    continue; //skip it

  ProcessFile(f);

  alreadySeen.Add(fnameLower);
}
```

The call to Add might need a "if the parent folder name is dev" check. I can't quite understand the requirement of what to do if multiple files of the same name are present in non dev folders

We could also do this with LINQ GroupBy, and group by the filename. GroupBy could break a list of filenames into a shorter list of unique filenames, each having an associated List of all the full filepaths together with their names. You either process only the first file out of the related list or you process all files in the list unless the first one is in a dev folder

```
var groupedByFilename = devFilesFirst.GroupBy(f => Path.GetFileName(f).ToLower());

foreach(var gf in groupedByFilename)
  ProcessFile(gf.First());
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your code and I think I understood now how it works. I believe there is one thing you misunderstood or maybe I didn't explained it clearly on my end. Sorry about that. For example if I have `files1.json`, `files2.json`, `files3.json` (or.txt files) in `folder1` level and let's say `files1.json` with different contents is also present in `dev` folder of `folder1` then in my final list I should only have `files1.json` file from `dev` folder of `folder1`. In your example I see you have both `files1.json` from `dev` folder and also `folder1` level as well.

Comment: I have updated my question at the end to add more details if that makes it clear to you.

Comment: I'm not really clear on whether you will never process any file with a same name as any previously processed file, or whether you will never process any file that that has the same name as a file previously seen in a dev folder?

Comment: Idea is if a file in dev has the same name as a file under subFolder, regardless of whether the content is the same, the file in dev should be selected and displayed in the final list. So if file in dev is new and its not present in the subFolder level then it should be added in the final list but if the file in dev is same as subfolder level then I will ignore that file from subfolder level but add dev file in the final list.

Comment: Also I don't want to add stage and prod file in my final list because I just care about dev folders file.

Comment: Then you'll have to add an exclude for stage and prod like I added an include for dev (I sort dev folders first; you can use the same technique in the where clause to omit stage and prod ie `Where(f => !"stage prod".Contains( the folder name)`

Comment: I edited the answer m, but not to include this "omit stage and prod"